# Wrap curve around spherical object. Also in two heights

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

i´m trying to make spherical shifter to my E30 like guy I found.
I have tried sort of bezier curves projected on but i kinda don´t work. Bending around is also not posibble because it is not perfect sphere.
Free hand bezier is not possible also.
Can anybody show me how wrap whole curve on object and do it in two heights? Thank you a lot  in advance :))

[image: shifter from top]